# where does DOMContentLoaded event listener fit in a vuejs model?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am new to web development. In my main.js file I have the following code which works.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
   // do some stuff
}
```

I have been reading about using vuejs and creating a model to help with two way binding. Where would the above code which check the DOM content has loaded 'fit' in a vue model? Or should it be seperate?

```
window.app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    some_propery_1: 0,
    some_propery_2: []
},
methods: {


}


})
```

Comment: Check `mounted` in Vue doc.

Comment: Depends on your case. Since DOM is generally shouldn't be accessed in Vue directly, there's probably no need for "do some stuff", also there may be no single point at which the app is in fully calm state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) "lives in a different world" than Vue.

Yes, you would use them **separately**, independently *(i.e. not in the same project, usually)*.

You should *(probably)* not use a `DOMContentLoaded` listener inside the `main.js` file that is to be used for Vue. <sub>*(only because you should keep Vue code and other code separate. Technically it would work, as long as you don't try to access Vue components)*</sub>.

In Vue, you would use an [`onMounted()`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle#onmounted) (or [`mounted`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle#mounted)) [lifecycle hook](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle) for things to be initially done.

#### DOM and Vue

You should *not* directly use DOM methods (like [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)) in Vue, you should only use the techniques/methods provided by Vue.

You can (technically) still have separate JavaScript files, independent from your Vue files, and DOM elements, independent from Vue components. There you might use DOM methods/events like `DOMContentLoaded`.

#### Execution order

`DOMContentLoaded` is executed after all [`module`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type#module) code (like Vue code) is executed ([`module` scripts behave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts) like [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer) scripts)

So `DOMContentLoaded` is executed *later* than the Vue "mounted" lifecycle hook.

But the call order shouldn't matter, because:

- you should not try to access Vue components from other scripts outside of Vue, and
- you should not access DOM nodes directly from Vue.